# Why the previous data cannot be queried when data directory did not change in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

After Apache IoTDB Version 0.12 restarts, the previous data cannot be queried, but the data in the current time series sequence can be found. However, new data can be written and the latest data can be found. I can still view the previous data in the data directory. The data directory was modified during installation, and has not been changed since then. The enable_wal parameter was modified from true to false, and later has changed back. Has anyone encountered this problem?

I tried to check existing information on official website, but it seems like no answer can be find for my specific case. Hope someone can answer the question on my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you modified "enable_wal" in Apache IoTDB, the structure of the storage directory will change. After you changed it back, IoTDB may not be able to read the previous data directory. You can try to backup your histrorical data, and use a command to guide IoTDB to query the backup pack to deal with it.